# Facing deadlock error on spring -boot application , database used is Azure MS SQL

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Error Text :
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 160) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

JPA version used : 2.7.12

@Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
select * from employee where employee_id=10

I am getting a deadlock issue on the below query :
update employee set emp_status='accept' where employee_id=10

How to resolve this issue ?

I changed different version of jpa .
I tried verifying the table indexes. But index is not causing issue.

Expectation :
When hit the application multiple times, deadlock issue should not come.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: It is Azure MS Sql database.